Caching Processed Data In Spark in the Event of Task Failures so as to Not Reprocess the same when the Task Restarts
We have a use-case wherein we need to cache certain data that has been processed so that Spark does not reprocess the same data in the event of task failures.
So say we have a thousand Foo objects for a particular task that we receive from a certain REST API call and Spark has processed say, some seven hundred of them when task failure occurs. Then when the task restarts, it shall be once again query the REST API using the partition parameters and receive the thousand objects. This time, it shouldn't re-process the seven hundred objects it has already processed but continue to process the remaining three hundred.
So is there anything available in Spark that serves the purpose ? Thanks.

Many ways the presist API call results, the most obvious one would be to cache results like below, or for each query object add retry policy within your method
Suggesting to handle throttling error retry in your local method makeAPICall to handle apis who reject you for too many requests
you can also repartition your api call requests in x partition to parrallelize to 2, 3, 4 parallel calls instead of hundreds
def func(spark: SparkSession) = {
    import spark.implicits._

    case class Foo(url: String)
    case class Result(url: String, response: String)

    val requests = Seq(
      Foo("https://www.google.com"),
      Foo("https://www.yahoo.com")
    ).toDS

    def makeAPICall(foo: Foo): Result = {
      // make API call
      Result(foo.url, "response")
    }

    val callResults = requests.map(makeAPICall).cache()
    
    callResults.show(false)
  }

